# How does a fragment shader work with sample1D and sample2D in a single texture unit?

Tags: textures, glsl

I am working with an OpenGL client code that only uses the default texture unit GL_TEXTURE0. It never creates a texture so it's always referring to the default texture name 0. As the drawing commands are issued, if a new texture is needed, it is created on the fly - either GL_TEXTURE_1D or GL_TEXTURE_2D.

My understanding is that both 1D and 2D textures will refer to the same unit = 0. Depending on which texture is being used - 1D or 2D - I pass a uniform flag to the shader so it knows how to work on the texture.

I also define a sampler1D AND a sampler2D in my fragment shader. I assign unit 0 to both - at least, that's my understanding of what I should do.

In the fragment shader I use the code

```
  uniform sampler1D texture1;
  uniform sampler2D texture2;
  uniform int texflagf;
  void main()
  {
 if(texflagf == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture1D(texture1, gl_TexCoord[0].s);
 } else if(texflagf == 2) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture2, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
 } else {
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
 }
  }
```

where texflagf takes values 0, 1, and 2, depending on whether I'm drawing without textures, with a 1D texture, or with a 2D texture. Note that in both I use gl_TexCoord[0], as only one unit is active. The vertex shader just passes these TexCoords through:

```
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

1) What I see is that if I first draw a 1D texture, the 2D texture doesn't display; and vice-versa. Why?

2) The client code assigns the unit via the code

```
     tex1Dloc = glGetUniformLocation(prog,"texture1");
     glUniform1i (tex1Dloc,0);
     tex2Dloc = glGetUniformLocation(prog,"texture2");
     glUniform1i (tex2Dloc,0);
```

This shows I'm setting the unit to both 1D and 2D texture to 0.

If I now set tex2Dloc to unit 1 - even though there is no reference to GL_TEXTURE1 in the entire code! - this seems to work. But I never even pass the texture coordinates for unit 1 in the vertex shader and still access gl_TexCoord[0] in both sampler1D and sampler2D.

I do not understand why setting one of the samplers to a different (non-existent!) unit works.

Can somebody explain to me what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: I have to say... *what?*. You do not create texture image units, you have a fixed set of them (GL 3.2 gives you 48 at minimum, GL 4.0 gives you 80). What they amount to are binding points for texture objects. Now, within a GLSL program it is invalid to reference the same texture image unit using two different types of samplers. However, as this is not something that can be detected at compile/link-time, this situation fails silently at run-time. You create undefined behavior, rather than an actual error state that you can detect.

Comment: Andon... thanks for the very quick reply!

Comment: Andon, thanks for the very quick reply! Sorry if I'm still confused - I inherited tens of thousands of GL code that I'm sorting through right now to add these shaders. My understanding is that one can attach 1D and 2D textures to the same unit - at the same time. But it seems that my problem is that whenever one texture is used, it just redefines the currently running texture name = 0. So texture 0 (in unit 0) changes from 1D to 2D as the program runs, and I should  generate 2 different textures, one for the 1D and one for the 2D.Then I could use 2 different samplers in the same unit.Right?

Comment: I used glGenTextures to generate different texture names for 1D and 2D textures - though still in the same unit GL_TEXTURE0. If I set the sampler1D and sampler2D units both to 0 the code still does not work properly. So I put one texture in GL_TEXTURE0 and the other in GL_TEXTURE1 and it all worked just fine. But I would really like to understand how to work with a 1D and a 2D texture in the same unit in a fragment shader.